# Play framework: secure WebSocket endpoint with OpenSSL X.509 certificate

Tags: ssl, https, playframework, websocket, openssl

I want to use SSL in Play framework (for Secure Websocket connections). I generated a certificate with OpenSSL in the following way:

```
// generate private key
sudo openssl genres -out ws.key 1024

// generate CSR
sudo openssl req -new -key ws.key -out ws.csr

// create self-signed X.509 certificate
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ws.csr -signkey ws.key -out ws.crt
```

I configured nginx as a secure proxy by using the generated *.crt* and *.key* files and everything works: clients (written with C++ and libwebsockets) are able to connect to Play to port 9443 and the communication is encrypted.
Part of *nginx* configuration is the following:

```
ssl_certificate         /Users/mattia/nginx/ssl/ws.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /Users/mattia/nginx/ssl/ws.key;
```

Now I don’t want to use nginx as secure endpoint but Play framework without any proxy. Play documentation explains how to use JKS certificates. How can I do with X.509 certificates generated with OpenSSL? What should I write in *application.conf*? Thanks.

Comment: I tried with the following parameters in application.conf:

    `https.keyStore="/Users/mattia/ssl/openssl/cert_with_key.pem"
https.keyStore.type="PEM"`


cert_with_key.pem is the concatenation of the private key and the certificate in PEM format. But when I start the server with:
    `activator run -Dhttps.port=9443`
I get the following output:
`[warn] play - Using generated key with self signed certificate for HTTPS.        This should not be used in production.`

This means that Play has ignored my PEM certificates in /Users/mattia/ssl/openssl. Why? I'm using Play 2.3.x